# Angular application in a docker container behing a nginx proxy

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, proxy

Hi have a little `angular5` application.  Running it locally with `ng serve` works fine.

Now, after doing a `ng build --prod`, I'm trying to put the `dist files` in production.

If I put the content of the dist folder in the root folder of an apache server, it's also working fine.

But I'm using `docker`.  So I have a `nginx containter` acting as a `proxy`.

In my `default.conf` I have things like that

```
set $portainer_upstream portainer:9000;

location /portainer/ {
    rewrite ^/portainer/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://$portainer_upstream;
}
```

It's working fine for several applications like portainer, phpmyadmin, ...

So I tried with

```
set $dmr_upstream angular-dmr;

location /dmr/ {
    rewrite ^/dmr/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://$dmr_upstream;
}
```

But it is not fully working.  If I go to `myhost.be/dmr/` my browser displays a blank page.  The application name is well displayed in the tab but nothing more.  And I have a 404 error for all resources.

```
Échec du chargement pour l’élément <script> dont la source est « http://myhost.be/inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js ».
Échec du chargement pour l’élément <script> dont la source est « http://myhost.be/polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js ».
Échec du chargement pour l’élément <script> dont la source est « http://myhost.be/main.dc3c390914b6d1b8c64c.bundle.js ».
```

What can I do ? I don't understand why the page is trying to load resources from http://myhost.be/...

> The solution

After building the dist application, the `index.html` contains

```
<base href="/">
```

It explains why the resources are loaded from http://myhost.be/...

The solution is to build with `ng build --target=production --base-href /dmr/`. Now the index.html contains

```
<base href="/dmr/">
```

And it's working.

But it means that if I want to change the `/dmr/` to `/newlocation/` I will have to change in my proxy (Ok, it's normal) but also rebuild the application with the new path and redeploy to the container.  I don't know if there is another way of doing.

Comment: What's `angular-dmr`? Hostname of the angular container? It is understood from nginx container as a valid hostname?

Comment: Yes, the angular app is inside a nginx containter named angular-dmr.

Comment: OK so it is listening on localhost, I guess you've to set the `proxy_pass` to the same location used to reach the app from within the container, something like `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;`

Comment: Ok, I have the solution.  See original post.